# Plugin Development: Eclipse hangs when testing plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am new to developing plugins, and was wondering what causes a test plugin to hang when started i.e. Eclipse is unresponsive.
I know that my code is working as I developed a voice recognition plugin to write to the screen what is said and when I open notepad everything I say is printed to notepad.

So I was wondering, am I missing something in the plugin life-cycle that causes the IDE to hang when my plugin is started?

```java
package recognise.handlers;

public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public SampleHandler() {
    }

    /**
     * the command has been executed, so extract extract the needed information
     * from the application context.
     */
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        boolean finish = false;
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "Recognise",
                "Starting Recognition");
        TakeInput start = new TakeInput();
        //Stage a = new Stage();
        //SceneManager scene = new SceneManager();
        try {
            start.startVoiceRecognition(finish);
            //scene.start(a);
        } catch (IOException | AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Does the start.startVoiceRecognition() need to be threaded?

Thanks in advance and let me know if you would like to see my manifest/activator etc.

**Conclusion**

Added a job separate to the UI thread

```
/*
 * Start a new job separate to the main thread so the UI will not
 * become unresponsive when the plugin has started
 */
  public void runVoiceRecognitionJob() {
    Job job = new Job("Voice Recognition Job") {
      @Override
      protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
     TakeInput start = new TakeInput();
     try {
        start.startVoiceRecognition(true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        // use this to open a Shell in the UI thread
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
      }

    };
    job.setUser(true);
    job.schedule();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown `start.startVoiceRecognition()` is running in the UI thread, and it will block the UI thread until it is finished and the app will be unresponsive during that time. So if it is doing a significant amount of work either use a `Thread` or use an Eclipse `Job` (which runs work in a background thread managed by Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

To unblock your UI you have to use Display thread.

```
 /**
         * the command has been executed, so extract extract the needed information
         * from the application context.
         */
        public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {

            boolean finish = false;
            IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
            MessageDialog.openInformation(
                    window.getShell(),
                    "Recognise",
                    "Starting Recognition");
            TakeInput start = new TakeInput();
            //Stage a = new Stage();
            //SceneManager scene = new SceneManager();
            try {
                start.startVoiceRecognition(finish);
                //scene.start(a);
            } catch (IOException | AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Your Popup ",
            "Your job has finished.");
      }
    });
            return null;
        }
```

You can use Display.getDefault().asyncExec() as mentioned above, so your UI will be unblocked, while your non UI code will be executing.